# Can I justify use of Repeated Measures for my data?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

New user & first time poster. I'm finalizing my dissertation and am searching for similar examples as my project or some way to justify one of our analyses. (I'm also open to better analysis ideas for possible publication later on if anyone has suggestions). I'll try to keep my introduction to the study brief but informative.

I collected data from participants related to their perceived religious support following loss to a suicide death, an accidental death, and a natural death. We aimed to compare responses to see if there are significant differences in perceived support based on type of loss. Thus, we have 3 religious support data points per subject. However, the order of the deaths varies among participants (i.e. some may be suicide-natural-accident while others may be accident-natural-suicide, etc.).

We ended up running Repeated Measures ANOVA - yet I've gotten push back (understandably) from committee members requesting that I find justification (such as a precedent in literature). That said, anyone know of a similar study/analyses in which RM ANOVA was used with variable time points as opposed to Time1 vs Time 2 vs Time 3, etc.?

Needless to say, stats is not one of my strong suits.

Answer (score 1):

Repeated measures does not mean longitudinal as your superiors seem to believe. One thing which might help is to allocate each respondent to one of six groups according to the order in which s/he experiences the events and then fit your model with that as a between subjects effect and type of event as a within subject effect. The interaction between them might be of scientific interest, or not. That is up to you, I think.